# Grouping and sum in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssms-2014

I am trying to extract the following columns from a sql table called Vouchers:

- Date,
- VoucherID,
- ValueIssued,
- ValueRedeemed,
- Valueexpired

That bit is straight forwards and returns the below data:

[image]

However I would like to show them

- by day,
- by voucherID

and then sum up the values for each individual voucherID to produce a view similar to the below:

[image]

Can anyone point me in the correct direction in regards to what sql code will do this?

I am using SSMS 2014

Comment: (1) Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  (2) A SQL Fiddle is always helpful.  (3) Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: what about DateExpired?

Comment: dateexpired is not important at this point

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straight forward

```
SELECT PosDate, VoucherId, SUM(ValueIssued), SUM(ValueRedeemed)  
FROM Vouchers  
GROUP BY PosDate, VoucherId
```

Note that column DateExpired isn't correct in this context. It should be either grouped by or removed entirely (as I did)